# RadioButtonList SelectedIndexChanged event not firing

Tags: asp.net

i want event to fire when selection of radio button list change. but it fire when i click on another button. not on selected index changed.

please note i'm also using bootstrap. without bootstarp it is working

my code is as follow.

### Source Code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     RepeatDirection="Horizontal" BorderStyle="None" CellPadding="5" 
     CssClass="col-xs-pull-12">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">All User</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem > SpeciFic Users</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

### Code behind

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Write("hi");
}
```

Comment: which browser you use?

Comment: Still unsure whats happening - can confirm this is failing only when using bootstrap. Also - when not using bootstrap page_Load is called instead of event bound to radio. - Will follow up once i have updates. ~ using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Also try displaying the list item to find out whether the event is firing or not.

Check out this link, it has a clear definition with an example...[Click here](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2009/03/how-to-use-onselectedindexchanged-event_18.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-3.3.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<%--<script src="js/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.js"></script>--%>
```

2 things for me:

1. **Removed script** *(unsure if versioning made the difference) the css file made no difference)* **duh**
2. **Needed a separate method to call** *( i had nearly all postback events calling the same method ~ 13 controls) (also unsure if every radio control needs their own callback method or not)*

`.aspx`

```
<div id="rdoSelectOptionsList" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">                    
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoShow" GroupName="rdoSelectOptions"  runat="server" Checked="true"  CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Show all" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoHide" GroupName="rdoSelectOptions" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Hide all" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblRdoSelectOptions" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-static"/>
</div>
```

`script`

```
$("#rdoSelectOptionsList :radio").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }
});
```